# What does the exclude_nodata_value argument to ST_DumpValues do?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Could anyone explain what the `exclude_nodata_value` argument to [`ST_DumpValues`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_DumpValues.html) does?

For example, given the following:

```
WITH
  -- Create a raster 4x4 raster, with each value set to 8 and NODATA set to -99.
  tbl_1 AS (
    SELECT
      ST_AddBand(
        ST_MakeEmptyRaster(4, 4, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 4326),
        1, '32BF', 8, -99
      ) AS rast
  ),
  -- Set the values in rows 1 and 2 to -99.
  tbl_2 AS (
    SELECT
      ST_SetValues(
        rast, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, -99, FALSE
      ) AS rast FROM tbl_1)
```

Why does the following select statement return `NULL`s in the first two rows:

```
SELECT ST_DumpValues(rast, 1, TRUE) AS cell_values FROM tbl_2;
```

Like this:

```
{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL},{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL},{8,8,8,8},{8,8,8,8}}
```

But the following select statement return `-99`s?

```
SELECT ST_DumpValues(rast, 1, FALSE) AS cell_values FROM tbl_2;
```

Like this:

```
{{-99,-99,-99,-99},{-99,-99,-99,-99},{8,8,8,8},{8,8,8,8}}
```

Clearly, with both statements the first two rows really contain `-99`s. However, in the first case (`exclude_nodata_value=TRUE`) these values have been masked (but not replaced) by `NULLS`.

Thanks for any help. The subtle differences between `NULL` and `NODATA` within PostGIS have been driving me crazy for several days.

Comment: It doesn't mean return no data, it means return null instead of a numeric value representing no data, such as -9999, which is arguably much cleaner, although I know some software packages use negative numbers to indicate no data.